# How can we hide the id from URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

my current URL is:
http://example.com/country/state/location/ls5/a1392f1d-1aee-470c-a159-07e6da071620
but what I want in my URL is: http://example.com/country/state/location/ls5
so how can we do it?I am having trouble with it. please guide me for the solution

Comment: Clear your Question what you want

Comment: @MizanurRahman don't be mean, answer the questioner not the question... the question might not make sense but the questioner does...

Comment: If you don't not send the `id` to the controller, how would your ever get it!

Comment: And why in the world would you want to _hide it_ anyway?

Comment: Your ID should not be sensitive data anyways when you need it to access the controller. If it is, you might have a bigger problem in terms of authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 2):

1. if you need the id to identify a record, then encrypt the id and use
   something else that does not identify your record directly...
2. if you are not using the id, just remove it...

> to answer your question fairly, everyone uses id in url in one way or
>   another, even stackoverflow ::
>   `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515076/how-can-we-hide-the-id-from-url`,
>   the id **48515076**